# do.call and rbind for list with order as new column name

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind, do.call

I'm having trouble reproducing this example, but I have a list composed of 253 objects, each with 4 columns with a length of 3000:

```
> str(data)
List of 253
 $ : num [1:3000, 1:4] 0.269 0.201 0.155 0.329 0.307 ...
 $ : num [1:3000, 1:4] 0.269 0.203 0.156 0.329 0.307 ...
 $ : num [1:3000, 1:4] 0.269 0.204 0.156 0.329 0.307 ...
 $ : num [1:3000, 1:4] 0.27 0.205 0.156 0.329 0.307 ...
```

I'm trying to use do.call and rbind to make a new object with the four columns and a another column that has the list number that looks like:

```
head(new)
     Name             [,1]               [,2]              [,3]              [,4]
[1,] 1    0.269077013009290 0.2522168552880047 0.262594373389746 0.216111758312960
[2,] 1    0.201348056547152 0.2611904119569095 0.264782271654359 0.272679259841580
[3,] 1    0.155481831431131 0.2599908556717349 0.412742657066444 0.171784655830690
[4,] 1    0.329421949966686 0.0968555482105167 0.365492803829526 0.208229697993272
[5,] 1    0.306985894860771 0.1407298652926539 0.331197510871706 0.221086728974869
[6,] 1    0.147101456518243 0.1521556602567531 0.402434842158681 0.298308041066323
```

Currently using the following code gives:

```
 new <- do.call(rbind, data)
 head (new)
             [,1]               [,2]              [,3]              [,4]
[1,] 0.269077013009290 0.2522168552880047 0.262594373389746 0.216111758312960
[2,] 0.201348056547152 0.2611904119569095 0.264782271654359 0.272679259841580
[3,] 0.155481831431131 0.2599908556717349 0.412742657066444 0.171784655830690
[4,] 0.329421949966686 0.0968555482105167 0.365492803829526 0.208229697993272
[5,] 0.306985894860771 0.1407298652926539 0.331197510871706 0.221086728974869
[6,] 0.147101456518243 0.1521556602567531 0.402434842158681 0.298308041066323
```

Any ideas on how I could add the "Name" column would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a 'Name' column with `Map` and then do the `rbind`

```
new <-  do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Name = seq_along(data), data))
```